Can you help to identify this TO-220 30-B20 Motorola 7913
Hi could you please help me to identify this component  TO-220 30-B20 M 7913, see image ?


That's a Motorola logo, not an M. Likely device made in 1979 week 13

Could be house-numbered part. Motorola did a lot of automotive parts, some of which were house numbered. You  can stick it in one of those automatic ID doodads, or check it yourself with a multimeter.  It's almost surely a BJT, Diode or diode array, Darlington or thyristor.
